# apt-get install fails to install OpenMediaVault - php5-pam dependency not available

Tags: pi-3, apt, php, media-server, media

While installing Open Media Vault following instructions on

- https://forum.htpcguides.com/Thread-Installing-OpenMediaVault-on-Pi3 or
- http://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/5302-Howto-install-OpenMediaVault-on-Debian-7-x-Wheezy/

I am facing a problem when running

```
sudo apt-get install openmediavault
```

some dependencies seems to be missing

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openmediavault : Depends: php5-pam but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: proftpd-mod-vroot but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: php5-proctitle but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea on how to fix that?

Other infos: RaspberryPi3 running Debian installed through Noobs.